# Google Web Designer - gotoPage issues

Tags: google-web-designer

I'm just finalising a MPU banner which consists of three pages :

**page1, page1_1, page1_2**

At the end of page1 I have a button, which when clicked goes to page1_1 the event for this is as follows:

**tap-area2 > action > GotoAndPlay  > pagedeck**

Configuration : page1_1
Transition: none
Duration: 1000
Easing: linear
Direction: top

That all works fine. Page1_1 appears and autoplays a short video. At the end of page1_1 I have a timeline event which loads page1_2. The event is as follows:

**page1_1 > event7 > GotoPage  > pagedeck**

Configuration : page1_2
Transition: none
Duration: 1000
Easing: linear
Direction: top

This works as planned. Page1_2 loads and plays a short animation. At the end of the sequence I would like to return to the first frame of page1 so that the animation loops again. I am using the current event (similar to the previous event above) at the end of the timeline:

**page1_2 > event8 > GotoPage  > pagedeck**

Configuration : page1
Transition: none
Duration: 1000
Easing: linear
Direction: top

On previewing the file the sequence does return to page1 but only at the end of the timeline - not frame 1.

Am I doing something wrong? I have tried using labels but it's still not working?
I come from a flash background so thought this would work similar to Scenes?

Any help gratefully received.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your last event will notify the pagedeck to go to page1, but page1 will resume timeline playback from its last state.

Additionally, you will need to notify the Timeline to start playing from the beginning of page1 by doing the following:

1. Add a Timeline label at the beginning of page1. Give it a name like 'page1_start'.
2. In addition to your existing event, add another event with the following info:

Target: page1_2

Event: Timeline/event8

Action: Timeline/gotoAndPlay

Receiver: page1

Configuration: Label: page1_start